# Fluently adding to a Collection (add and return the value)

Tags: java, collections, guava, apache-commons

Time and again, I find myself in the situation where I want to use a value, and add it to a collection at the same time, e.g.:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
person1.setName(addTo(names, "Peter"));
person2.setName(addTo(names, "Karen"));
```

(Note: using java.util.Collection.add(E) doesn't work of course, because it returns a boolean.)

Sure, it's easy to write a utility method myself like:

```
public static <E> E addTo(Collection<? super E> coll, E elem) {
    coll.add(elem);
    return elem;
}
```

But is there really not something like this already in JavaSE, Commons Collections, Guava, or maybe some other "standard" library?

Comment: Guava would never make such a "helper". Commons, maybe.

Comment: @shmosel: I agree, but maybe Guava could have it in a different form, e.g. as a wrapper, similar to their FluentIterable.

Comment: Isn't it considered a bad habbit to try to do 2 things at the same time? A method called addToCollectionAndReturnValue doesn't feel right to me. I also don't understand why you are looking for a "standard" solution for this when you have written the solution in this post.

Comment: @Wesley: I do see a little bit of a downside maybe, but personally wouldn't consider it a bad habit, as it avoids having to write two lines each time, creating lots of local variables, which can easily lead to mistakes and code that's hard to read. Also consider that, for example, java.util.Map also has a fluent method "V put(K key, V value)".

Comment: Usually what people ask for is something that returns the collection, so one can chain calls like `coll.add(a).add(b).add(c);`. Also note that `Map.put()` returns the **previous** value, not the argument.

Answer (score 4):

The following will work if you use [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/):

```
MutableList<String> names = Lists.mutable.empty();
person1.setName(names.with("Peter").getLast());
person2.setName(names.with("Karen").getLast());
```

The `with` method returns the collection being added to so you can easily chain adds if you want to.  By using `getLast` after calling `with` on a `MutableList` (which extends `java.util.List`) you get the element you just added.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a very strange pattern to me. A line like `person1.setName(addTo(names, "Peter"))` seems inverted and is very difficult to properly parse:

> An existing person object is assigned a name, that name will first be added to a list of names, and the name is "Peter".

Contrast that with (for example) `person1.setName("Peter"); names.add(person1.getName());`:

> Make "Peter" the name of an existing person object, then add that name to a list of names.

I appreciate that it's two statements instead of one, but that's a very low cost relative to the unusual semantics you're proposing. The latter formatting is easier to understand, easier to refactor, and more idiomatic.

I would be willing to wager that many scenarios that might benefit from your `addTo()` method have other problems and would be better-served by a different refactoring earlier on.

---

At its core the issue seems to be that you're trying to represent a complex data type (`Person`) while simultaneously constructing an unrelated list consisting of a particular facet of those objects. A potentially more straightforward (and still fluent) option would be to construct a list of `Person` objects and then transform that list to extract the values you need. Consider:

```
List<Person> people = ImmutableList.of(new Person("Peter"), new Person("Karen"));
List<String> names = people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(toList());
```

Notice that we no longer need the isolated `person1` and `person2` variables, and there's now a more direct relationship between `people` and `names`. Depending on what you need `names` for you might be able to avoid constructing the second list at all, e.g. with [`List.forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

If you're not on Java 8 yet you can still use a functional syntax with [Guava's functional utilities](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained). The caveat on that page is a worthwhile read too, even in Java-8-land.